error: cannot find symbol parcel.writeInt(getImageResource());
error: cannot find symbol
parcel.writeInt(getImageResource());
^
symbol:   method getImageResource()
location: class MyEventDay
 @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeSerializable(getCalendar());
        parcel.writeInt(getImageResource());
        parcel.writeString(mNote);
    }


